# Power of a sparse matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to compute the power of a sparse matrix in matlab without converting it to a full matrix.  If I try

```
b = a^0.5
```

where a is a sparse matrix, I get the error "Use full(x)^full(y).".  However, converting a to a full matrix defeats the purpose of having a sparse matrix to begin with.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: This [file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25782-mpower2-a-faster-matrix-power-function) may interest you.

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is that it only allows integer powers, and I'm trying to raise to 0.5.

Comment: Do you have any extra structure you can exploit in your matrix?

Answer (score 3):

The square root of your sparse matrix will not be sparse anyway in general. So there is no gain in having it sparse.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to compute the root yourself. Assume a kxk square matrix,then

```
[v d] = eigs ( a, k ) 
r = v*(d^0.5)*v'
```

However, this will not work for nonsymmetric or complex matrices, and it really beats the purpose of having a sparse matrix, because you produce another couple matrices which are full. Unfortunately, the eigenvectors are not expected to be sparse. Thus, you see why it is required to work with full matrices.